# In a metric space, if $A$ is open and $B$ is closed, is $A + B$ open or closed?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $A, B \in E^n$, and consider their sum $A + B = \{x+y \mid x \in A, y \in B\}$.
Suppose that $A$ is open and $B$ is closed.

- Is it always true that $A+B$ is open?
- Is it always true that $A+B$ is closed?

Comment: What is $E^n$?${}$

Comment: $E^n=\mathbb R^n$? Also what do you have so far? Don't tell me you have no idea on both questions.

Comment: Hint: $A+B=\bigcup_{b\in B}(b+A)$ therefore open.

Comment: I dont know wat $E^n$ is?this may be a set of intervals!!

Answer (score 2):

Try simple examples. The most basic closed set, for instance, is a point. What happens in this case?